# Cannot access Redis Server in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, redis

I have setup my Redis server in AWS and I am unable to connect to it from an external IP although I can access it from within the same server.

I have also done the following:

1. Added an inbound rule to the security group of the instance to allow access to all traffic (to test).
2. Checked whether bind property is commented in reds.config file

Still I cannot access it using
redis-cli -h xxx.xxx.xxx.xx -p 6379

Please help

Update:

I can telnet to the port so there must be something in Redis itself which is not allowing access?

netstat results:

[ec2-user@ip-10-10-102-0 ~]$ netstat -a | egrep 'Proto|LISTEN'
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                       *:*                         LISTEN
tcp        0      0 localhost:smtp              *:*                         LISTEN
tcp        0      0 *:6379                      *:*                         LISTEN
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                       *:*                         LISTEN

Answer (score -1):

Did you trey setting the IP to bind to in redis.conf? For example:

```
# bind 192.168.1.100 10.0.0.1
# bind 127.0.0.1
```